# OAuth: Not able to see Google email addresses after login

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth

I would like to get the email address from the Google user. To do this, I am using this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

After login, user gets redirected to this controller:

```java
@Controller
public class OAuthController {
    @GetMapping("/google")
    public ResponseEntity<String> google() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            OAuth2User user = (OAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();

            String email = user.getAttribute("email");
            System.out.println(email);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Email");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
```

However, I always get into the else-statement. This is the return of `authentication`:

[image]

And this is my security configuration:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/welcome").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    );

    http.httpBasic();
    http.logout().permitAll();
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

In the *OAuth consent screen* of Google Cloud, I have added my email address as a test user and added the scopes *.../auth/userinfo.email* and *.../auth/userinfo.profile*. My application.yml looks like this:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <my-client-id>
            client-secret: <my-client-secret>
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/google
          scope:
            - email
            - profile
```

When signing in, Google highlights that the email address will be shared. See:

[image]

So why am I not able to see the email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fix your application properties

Apparently, the `openid` scope is missing.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <my-client-id>
            client-secret: <my-client-secret>
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/google
          scope:
            - email
            - profile
            - openid
```

#### Fix your controller code

If `openid` scope was there and if the user was successfully authenticated with `oauth2Login` (`authorization_code` flow), the `OAuth2User` should actually be an `OidcUser`, which extends `OAuth2User` and `IdTokenClaimAccessor`. This means than you should be able to do as follow:

```java
@Controller
public class OAuthController {

    @GetMapping("/google")
    public ResponseEntity<String> google() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (    authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth &&
                oauth.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser oidcUser) {
            System.out.println(oidcUser.getEmail());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not an OIDC user");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

You should also be able to explicitly access the ID token claims with for instance `oidcUser.getIdToken().getEmail()`.

#### Fix your Java configuration

According to the logs you linked in the comments, the request is not authorized (it is an anonymous request). Your security filter-chain is a mess with at least 3 different mechanisms for requests authorization (Basic, JWT Bearer and OAuth2 client with login).

You should use only one request authorization mechanism per `SecurityFilterChain` bean (when you define several, `@Order` those beans and put a `securityMatcher` in each but the one with lowest precedence). For your experimentation, I suggest you start by using only OAuth2 client with login:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain oauth2ClientnWithLoginFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Don't  ever disable CSRF protection when sessions are enabled (OAuth2 clients with login need sessions)
    http.csrf(Customizer.withDefaults());
    http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

We don't have the code for your `jwtFilter` nor the origin of the requests using it, but it is most probably an artifact of worst practices. If your intention is to provide SPA (Angular, React, Vue, ...) or mobile application with a JWT to authorize request, it is definitely a worst practice: such frontends should be authorized with session cookie (and CSRF protection) using your OAuth2 client filter-chain with `oauth2Login`. **OAuth2 tokens should remain on servers you trust**. In any case, tokens should be delivered by authorization server to clients. This clients use the tokens to authorize the request it send to resource server. Even if you merge several of this 3 actors into a single application, each should have its own security filter-chain.

If you are using OAuth2, clients running on servers without the context of a user should probably be using `client_credentials` flow instead of Basic auth.

I suggest you start by reading the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) section of my tutorials. You should be able to better define what kind of request authorization mechanism you want. Then refer to the right tutorials to configure your application(s): reorganize the SecurityFilterChain(s) and configure several in a single app if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but the output is "Not an OIDC user".

Comment: Please see the trace, after the user has logged in: https://justpaste.it/oauth

Comment: Most probably because you forgot the `openid` scope. I edited my answer to add this.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, `openid` was missing. I have just added it but I still get the output "Not an OIDC user".

Comment: See my updated answer. Sorry to tell that, but you have a rather long journey to fix your Java configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Yes, the problem was `auth.requestMatchers("/api/welcome").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()`. I have changed it to `http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth .requestMatchers("/").permitAll() .anyRequest().authenticated() );` and now it works fine!

Comment: I just added a minimal filter-chain. I suggest you start from there.